# Is the detonation of a nuclear projectile dangerous for the atmosphere?

Tags: nuclear-physics

If you make a nuclear explosion in the atmosphere, will it cause its destruction or any damage to it?
Is it possible to damage a layer of the atmosphere, for example, one that protects from cosmic radiation?

Comment: Nuclear weapons have been exploded on the ground, in the atmosphere, and in space. The atmosphere is still here.

Comment: reading this might help https://thereader.mitpress.mit.edu/devastating-effects-of-nuclear-weapons-war/

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely that any single man-made explosion will cause global or long term effects to the Earth's atmosphere (apart from a small increase in the general level of background radiation). The energy released in even the largest man-made explosion is far smaller than that released in natural geological events - the energy released in the [1980 eruption of Mount St. Helens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1980_eruption_of_Mount_St._Helens), for example, was at least $20$ times greater than the largest nuclear weapon in the US arsenal.

However, other human activities such as burning fossil fuels, releasing CFCs etc. have had and continue to have massive effects on our atmosphere.

Comment: @Aleksey That sounds like a really bad idea for very many reasons, but it's not a physics question.